# Making a node's mixed case value to all lowercase (C)

Tags: c, char

The goal of this code is to go through a linked list which I have passed in and compare a substring to a string to determine if it is in it. If the substring is in the string, then I print the line. Unfortunately, if the substring is foo and the string is "ConFoosing", it wont consider it a match, how can I make it so that "tester", my line is all lowercase before the comparison? toLower() wont work on a char * and Im not sure how to convert a char* to a char str[]

```
  static int wordMode(struct node *head, char* word)
    {
    struct node *ptr;
    int count = 0;

    printf("word count\n");
    for (ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next){
        char * tester = ptr->filler;
        char *pch = strstr(tester, word);
        if(pch){
            printf("LINE: %s\n", tester);
            count++;

        }
        printf("%d", count);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used strcasestr to solve it, exampels and documentation can be found here

http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasestr